Why does the VIC-20 tinymon relocator escape $00 bytes?
Jim Butterfields tinymon1 monitor for the VIC-20 was distributed as a BASIC program with appended machine language code, as is typical for many CBM machine-language programs.
However, in this case the machine-language code is in two parts: a relocator followed by the monitor itself. The relocation code reads the monitor code following it and copies it up to the top of available memory, moving BASIC's top-of-memory pointer down to the start of the monitor so that it can be used at the same time as BASIC. I've created a minimal disassembly of the relocation code. (The vic20-tinymon directory in that repo contains further documentation, including the source of the PRG file that I'm disassembling.)
One thing that's interesting about the relocation code and data to be relocated is that it seems to be "escaping" $00 bytes: any $00 byte found in the source data being relocated is ignored unless followed by a second $00 byte, in which case only one $00 byte is copied. (This has made further disassembly somewhat annoying, since I now have to do that transformation as well before disassembly, rather than just disassembling the (position-independent) monitor code in place.)
Why is the monitor code escaped in this way, rather than appending the unmodified monitor to the PRG and copying it without changes? The relocation code itself seems not to need to be escaped in this way; there are two "plain" $00 bytes in it that seem to work just fine. (They are at $1061 as part of LDY #$00 and and $10B8 as part of JMP ($0037), though admittedly the latter has non-code $00 bytes after it.)

Guess: Feature to allow to edit bytes in-memory, using 00 as placeholders that are ignored, e.g. if you want to delete a byte.

The reason turns out to be that, while the relocator is position-independent code (PIC), the monitor itself is not.
The $00 bytes are "suffix bytes" (because the copy is done from end to start) that themselves are not copied. Upon encountering a $00 suffix byte, the relocator does one of two things:

If the preceding byte is a $00, that $00 is copied and the relocator carries on after that as normal.

If the preceding byte is not $00, the preceding word is taken as a signed offset relative to the destination end address. This offset is in standard little-endian form, with the MSB in the higher-memory byte (and thus read first, as we go backwards through the code) and the LSB in the lower-memory byte. Before copying, the destination address end address is added to that offset to produce an absolute address that will work in the destination location.


If you're interested in more details, I've created the following annotated disassembly of the code. (It can also be found in this repo, along with a Test script that builds the code with ASL and confirms that it matches the original code. There is also an annotated disassembly of the monitor itself.)
;   VIC-20 tinymon1 relocator, by Jim Butterfield
;
;   This program is position-indepenent code that lives just after the
;   BASIC program that SYSs it. The code to be relocated (the monitor
;   itself) starts after this with an END ($BF) byte preceeding it, and
;   extends to the end of the BASIC file.
;
;   The copy is done from end to beginning, with the destination end
;   `destend` starting just below MEMSIZ, and `src` and `memsize` moving
;   downwards as the copy progresses. When complete, FRETOP is also
;   moved down to match MEMSIZ; moving these BASIC variables down keeps
;   it from stomping on the relocated code.
;
;   The relocated code need not be position-independent. Any $00 byte in
;   the code being relocated is a "suffix byte" that is not copied but
;   indicates one of two actions to be taken on bytes preceeding it. If the
;   preceeding byte is $00, it is just copied. Otherwise the two preceeding
;   bytes are taken as a signed 16-bit offset (in the usual little-endian
;   format, with the LSB lower in memory than the MSB) from the end address
;   of the program; the end address of the destination is added to this
;   to produce the relocated absolute address.
;

            page 0          ; no page breaks
            cpu 6502

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
;   System parameters

vartab      equ $2D         ; start of BASIC variable space, and thus the
                            ;   first byte after the machine-language code
                            ;   appended to the BASIC program
fretop      equ $33         ; Top of free mem for vars and thus bottom of BASIC
                            ;   dynamic string area that lives below memsiz.
memsiz      equ $37         ; Top of all RAM available to BASIC. We move this
                            ;   pointer down as we copy both to keep track
                            ;   of the current copy address and, at the end,
                            ;   leave it set so BASIC will not stomp on our
                            ;   code.

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
;   Our variables. We use various locations that are not used
;   by BASIC while we're runing the relocation.

src         equ $22         ; pointer to current source byte to be relocated
                            ;   (we copy from the end, vartab-1, downward)
destend     equ $24         ; pointer to end of relocated program (constant)

pmul        equ $26         ; temporary storage for a byte
temp        equ pmul

END         equ $BF         ; Value indicating that our copy is complete.

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            org $104F

sysentry    nop             ; BASIC `SYS` command enters here
            lda vartab      ; source end is at end of our appended ML code
            sta src
            lda vartab+1
            sta src+1
            lda memsiz      ; destination end is current top of memory;
            sta destend     ;   we will copy the program downwards from there
            lda memsiz+1
            sta destend+1
nextbyte    ldy #$00        ; index 0 to access location in ZP word
            lda src         ; decrement MSB?
            bne +           ;    no
            dec src+1       ;   yes
+           dec src
            lda (src),Y     ; is next byte $00?
            bne nzbyte      ;    no: copy it as is
            ;
            ;   $00 byte suffix found; handle preceeding byte(s) specially.
            lda src         ; move to next byte
            bne +
            dec src+1
+           dec src
            lda (src),Y     ; load next byte. = $00?
            beq copy        ;   yes: copy a single $00 byte
            ;
            ;   We have a signed word offset (always negative) from the end
            ;   of the program; add it to `destend` addr to get the address
            ;   in the relocated code. Note that, because we're copying from
            ;   end to beginning, the first byte we've read after the $00
            ;   is the MSB and the byte we read after that, lower in
            ;   memory, will be the LSB.
            sta temp        ; save MSB of offset
            lda src         ; move down to preceeding byte
            bne +
            dec src+1
+           dec src
            lda (src),Y     ; load LSB of offset
            clc
            adc destend     ; and add LSB of end of relocated code
            tax             ; save absolute LSB
            lda temp        ; restore MSB of offset
            adc destend+1   ; add MSB of end of relocated code
            pha             ; save absolute MSB
            lda memsiz      ; move current copying addr down to relocated MSB
            bne +
            dec memsiz+1
+           dec memsiz
            pla             ; restore MSB
            sta (memsiz),Y  ; save to upper byte
            txa             ; restore LSB and save to lower byte
            ; FALLTHROUGH

copy        pha
            lda memsiz      ; decrement end-of-BASIC-memory pointer
            bne +
            dec memsiz+1
+           dec memsiz
            pla
            sta (memsiz),Y  ; and copy our byte there
            clc
            bcc nextbyte    ; BRA

nzbyte      cmp #END        ; finished copy?
            bne copy        ;    no: copy this byte
            lda memsiz      ; set up empty BASIC string heap
            sta fretop      ;   at new top of memory
            lda memsiz+1
            sta fretop+1
            jmp (memsiz)    ; start monitor


I enjoy self answers.  The annotation disassembly is not too long (in my opinion) that it couldn't be reasonably included in the answer itself, if you think it would improve the answer.

Using byte relocation offsets and switching to word offsets on a special marker is a typical way to lay out relocation tables. Many Motorola 68k relocatable binary formats work that way.

@WayneConrad Sure; that seems reasonable, especially since I don't anticipate any future improvements to the disassembly. I've added it.

I don't know 6502 assembly language. But your description makes me ask, what if you want to encode a relocation in which the MSB of the relocation entry should be a zero? Or is this never needed?

@ecm Nice catch! You're right, and I now realise that my description of the relocation offsets was wrong; they're actually from the end of the program, not the current copy address. I've updated the documentation and comments in both the repo and the code in this answer.
